# Facebook post in group wall using Graph API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a android application which is requires posting in groups created by the user.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("link","www.google.com");
params.putString("message","Group Message");

try {
  String res =    fb.request(GROUP_ID+"/feed",params);

 Log.w("Response",""+res);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {

 e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}

 }
```

Also i'm using the following permissions,

```
public static final String[] permissions = {"user_photos","friends_groups","read_stream","user_groups","publish_stream"};
```

But when i execute this, no exception is raised  and the post is not made in the group's wall.

When i tried to create @Mentions using, `@[user_id:name]` i'm not even getting the hyperlinks.

Can anyone help me in solving the above said two issues.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the `fb.request` method uses a GET request. As you are intending to create a new post, you need to use the POST method. Doing this is simple - just pass a third argument (`httpMethod`) as "POST".

For example:
`String res =    fb.request(GROUP_ID+"/feed",params,"POST");`

For more info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/ayncrequest/

Also, the first argument needs to be a full URL, not just an ID - `https://graph.facebook.com/GROUP_ID/feed`

Of course, I'm making an assumption based on your variable name.

Comment: Thanks @Callum McLean, it worked. Any idea about @[user_id:name] ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not much of a native Android dev, and for some reason, I can't seem to find it in the SDK docs, so I can't offer much help there, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

```
String response = mFacebook.request(GROUP_ID+"/feed",bundle,"POST");
```

by using the above method we can post at group wall.
first argument GROUP_ID should be a string which is numeric having 15 digits.It should not be a url.

second argument bundle is the bundle which you want to passed.